# Access syntax error when using Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007

I have those two tables (Members and Now) I just need to make sure that no one in Members is actually in Now. Both tables have different structures but can be joined on firsname, lastname and postalcode.

So I tried this (in access)

```
SELECT Members.Prenom, Members.Nom, Members.Adresse, Members.[Adresse 2], Members.ville, Members.Province, Members.CodePostal
FROM Members
Left JOIN now ON (members.prenom = now.firstname AND members.nom = now.lastname
AND members.codepostal = now.postcode) WHERE now.id IS NULL
```

And it gives me a wonderful error message

> invalid use of '.' ' ' or '()'. in query expression

May someone enlighten me on what I did wrong?

Comment: What version of Access are you using again?

Comment: Members and members are not the same thing. Try matching the casing and see if your error is different

Comment: Pretty sure now is a restricted keyword? try wrapping `` around the columns

Comment: That would be 2007. 
The casing didn't change the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you cannot use 'now' as a table name, there are certain reserved words that MS Access need (in this case for function Now(), I guess the error message is telling you have missed the parentesis' ()). You could try encasing it in square brackets but **I would strongly recommend changing your table name**. A useful format I use is to prefix objects such as `tblTableName`, `qryQueryName`, `rptReportName`, `frmFormName` etc but whatever works for you.

```
SELECT Members.Prenom, Members.Nom, Members.Adresse, Members.[Adresse 2], 
    Members.ville, Members.Province, Members.CodePostal
FROM Members
Left JOIN [now] a ON (members.prenom = a.firstname AND members.nom = a.lastname
AND members.codepostal = a.postcode) WHERE a.id IS NULL
```